# How do I write the wordpress function "is_front_page()" in twig Timber code?

Tags: php, wordpress, twig

My goal is to simply output something only on the index page of my wordpress using Twig code. I have set a static page called Home.

I have tried this in my base.twig:

```
{% if is_front_page %}
 Homepage content
{% endif %}
```

But this doesn't do anything and I just find can't easily find it for some reason.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Timber [comes with the `fn`](https://github.com/jarednova/timber/blob/master/lib/timber-twig.php#L95) (also has alias of `function`) that let's you execute external PHP functions. So something like this would work:

```
{% if fn('is_front_page') %}
  Homepage content
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Nice I had already found a solution but this another way to do it! Thanks for letting me know about this function!

Answer (score 12):

I like to keep special functions outside of my twig templates. In Timber you can define your own context where you can set your own variables.

Create a file called `front-page.php` and add:

```
<?php

$context = Timber::get_context();

// Set a home page variable
$context['is_front_page'] = 'true';

Timber::render(array('home.twig'), $context);
```

then you can use `is_front_page` as a variable just like you wanted:

```
{% if is_front_page %}
 Homepage content
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This was almost too obvious after I thought about it...which is probably why it works so well.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a global content by extending the timber_context fitler.

Add the below into you functions.php file and it will add to all templates using calling Timber::get_context();.

```
add_filter('timber_context', 'add_to_context');
function add_to_context($context){
    /* Add to Timber's global context */
    $context['is_front_page'] = is_front_page();
    return $context;
}
```

Comment: This should be the preferred way for best practices and maintainable code