# Timber (Twig) how to call wordpress functions

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber, twig-extension

In Timber is this function

```
{{post}}
```

where you get things like

```
{{post.post_title}}
```

but there are other functions in WordPress like

```
get_the_permalink();
```

which are not accessible from post.get_the_permalink or post.get_permalink

these are the variables i can access

- ID
- post_author
- post_date
- post_date_gmt
- post_content
- post_title
- post_excerpt
- post_status
- comment_status
- ping_status
- post_password
- post_name
- to_ping
- pinged
- post_modified
- post_modified_gmt
- post_content_filtered
- post_parent
- guid
- menu_order
- post_type
- post_mime_type
- comment_count
- filter

As this Timber documentation describes there are actions [[Timber Doc]](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/wp-integration/#the-content) but you would have to define each function in the functions.php file ... which means i would have to create each already existing function from php and "redirect" it to the wordpress function. Then bind it to Twig.

Also there was a way as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31767735/how-do-i-write-the-wordpress-function-is-front-page-in-twig-timber-code) which is now [deprecated](https://github.com/timber/timber/wiki/WP-Integration)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I believe you should use `{{post.link}}` to get the Permalink.

Second, if you find you often need to call php functions from your twig templates, you might not separate between code and template enough. 
However, since they allow you to call Wordpress-Actions from the template, you could always write a single action in your functions.php that will, depending on the parameters, call the php-function you want. That would be very similar to the `fn()` call that was suggested.

Comment: i realy dont like the concept of [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) but i probably need to use them now

Comment: Use [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/function.call-user-func.php) if you want it to feel less dirty ;) OTOH, how much do you really need to call from your template, and is that still a template if it's a lot?

Comment: yeah i want a clean template but have to use them to get the data where it belongs to ....  but anyway i will do it this way ty :)

Answer (score 25):

You can call any function by using for example

```
{{ function('get_permalink', post.ID) }}
```

more infos:
https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/functions/